# PayPal Express & Store: Payment has already been made for this InvoiceID

Tags: expresso-store

I am setting up Store using PayPal Express. I am using a sandbox account for testing.

When I go to check out and submit payment I get the following error:

Payment has already been made for this InvoiceID.

What is going on here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like for whatever reason you're passing a duplicate Order ID to Paypal when you try to make the purchase. If it's a development setup then it could be that in testing you've been making and deleting orders or moving databases which can sometimes cause a bit a few problems with database normalisation.

Store will always look to auto increment the Order ID however so on a clean install you should never get this issue. If it persists and you're just running some tests then I'd try wiping the slate clean and starting afresh to ensure that old or inconsistent data isn't the cause of the issue.

Comment: Thanks! I was using the same sandbox account that I used for a previous installation so it was indeed passing an ID that already existed. Set up a new sandbox account and all works fine.

Comment: Note you can also disable this check in your PayPal account settings. Store already checks for duplicate payments, so it's not necessary for PayPal to do this as well.